# How to get UK keyboard layout in Centos 5.11 console

Tags: keyboard-layout

I have tried loadkeys 'gb' and I get cannot open file gb

I tried localectl but as 5.11 doesn't use systemd this doesn't work

I have used loadkeys uk successfully, however it gives me what I think is the 'ukraine' keyboard and things are still messed up

-- I don't want to change things permanently, just while I'm logged in.

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to [unix.se] since it's more about how unix works than about systems administration. This doesn't mean that the question is bad, just that it's more likely to get a good answer there.

Comment: Ah thanks Jenny, I should of likely asked it there in the first place! (I asked here after reading similar questions here.)